# EXC_BAD_ACCESS with Swift app using Core Data and Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, memory, firebase

**Problem:**
I am getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error in my app and I think it is because of thread-safety related code (self.sharedContext.performBlockAndWait) in my closures. But I cannot figure out why the problem exists. I will appreciate any help in figuring this out.

My project is in Swift 2 on Xcode 7.

**Project repository:** https://github.com/qwertyshan/HungryBaby

**My object graph looks like the following:**

```
class Recipe:
  var name: String
  var version: Double
  ...   // some more simple properties
  var method: [Method]   // object array
  var ingredients: [Ingredient]  // object array
  var nutrition: Nutrition // object
```

**The program flow is something like the following:**

In LoginVC.swift:

Line 101: getDataOnLogin( ) downloads data from network and parses it as an array of "recipe" dictionaries
Line 148: generateRecipe( dictionary ) is called to create Recipe object graph

- generateRecipe() in turn calls generateIngredients(), generateMethod(), and generateNutrition().
- Each of these methods initialize their objects on the SharedContext and add a relationship to the calling Recipe object. 
  Crash occurs on line 154 in LoginVC.swift with error: "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0x2)".

I know this is a memory error, but I don't know why it is being triggered. Can someone please look at my project and provide some insights into the cause of this crash?

**Reproduction steps:**

1. Run application workspace "HungryBaby.xcworkspace"
2. On UI, tap “Login Anonymously” to download recipe data.
3. Step through breakpoints until app crashes.

If you're taking the time to read this, thanks a ton!

Comment: On line 113 of that same file you are using `data as! [[String:AnyObject]]`.  Are you certain that data is the correct type for that `as!` call?

Comment: Yes. That data parses properly.

Comment: i did not got any crash .

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with thread safety in Core Data. I am answering the question so others don't have to spend any more time on it.